# new computer, git pull origin is asking for a password

Tags: windows, git

on my new computer, I setup git and my putty.exe and ssh key etc. just fine.

So I do a:

```
git pull origin
```

and then at the command prompt, I am asking for a password.

I have no idea what password it wants, and then it also asks for my server's password after a few failed attempts at the first password.

it asks for:

```
blahblah@serveradmin.com password:
```

What is going on?

(my git rep is hosted on a shared unix isp)

**I already setup pageant to use my private key, and it gave me a popup to enter my passphrase.  This is how it works on my old computer, and then when I open git-bash and do a 'git pull origin' it works fine without asking me anything.**

**Update II**

So let me summarize what is happending here:

I have the exact same setup at my office computer (windows7) (desktop), and it works fine w/o asking me any questions.  All I do b4 using git is run a .bat file that loads up pageant.exe:

```
C:\putty\pageant.exe "E:\code\pg_pk.ppk"
```

Then doing a **git pull origin** works fine, doesn't ask me for any password.

I had this on my laptop also, and it worked just like my office computer UNTIL I installed windows 7 on it.  Now it asks me for a password even though pageant.exe is running (I can see it in my taskbar, and the key is loaded).

So today I grabbed the .bat file and the entire /putty folder and put it on my laptop, still doesn't work, it is asking me for a password when I type: `git pull origin`

(I am running the same version of git on both computers)

Really confused, what could it be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't clear from your question whether or not you set up Git to actually *use* PuTTY. What is the content of your `GIT_SSH` environment variable?

It should be set to the full path to `plink.exe`. Even better yet: if you also use TortoiseSVN or TortoiseHg, set `GIT_SSH` to *their* `TortoisePlink.exe`. `TortoisePlink` has been modified to not read from the standard input, but instead pop up a dialog window, if something goes wrong. Git redirects standard input, so that you *cannot* actually type anything into `plink`, if, for example, your server's IP address changes and `plink` asks you to type `yes` to confirm it, that won't work. (You'll have to invoke `plink` or `putty` manually, then say `yes` and they will save it in the registry.) `TortoisePlink` will instead pop up a `Yes`/`No` dialog box.

Comment: I have a .bat file that I click on b4 using Git-Bash, it has:  c:\putty\pageant.exe "e:\code\pg_pk.ppk"

Comment: and this works on my office computer, and worked on my laptop, but now when I installed windows7 on my laptop, its not working? (my office computer is w7)

Comment: @Blankman: This *still* doesn't answer the question whether you set up Git to actually *use* PuTTY. If you set up Git to use OpenSSH, you can start Pageant all you want, OpenSSH doesn't give a rat's ass about Pageant. So, I repeat: what is the content of your `GIT_SSH` environment variable?

Comment: Jorg, I don't recall every having to set the GIT_SSH, but I might have forgotten?  How do I set the environmental var ?  Should I just point it to plink.exe or do I need to point it to my key also?

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I put the full name (including path) of TortoisePlink.exe.  eg : C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoisePlink.exe

Comment: `TortoisePlink.exe` is so much better than `Putty/plink.exe`. It finally pops up a window asking for my password, whereas `plink.exe` errors out with `fatal: Could not read from remote repository.  Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.`

Answer (score 2):

You ssh key passphrase.

To remedy, you can recreate a key on your new machine using `ssh-keygen` and then save in the git origin

Comment: I already set that when I clicked on my .bat file that starts pageant, hmm...very strange!

Answer (score 0):

I'd double-check your SSH keys--looks like it's not properly sending your identity.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that pageant sometimes just does not work. IMHO it is far easier to set it up using a blank password key with command line ssh client. From memory:

1. Generate public/private key using git bash:

   `ssh-keygen -t RSA -C email@address`

DO NOT specify password.

2. Upload the the contents of %USERPROFILE%.ssh\id_rsa.pub
3. Git should just work, including windows command line, git bash, tortoise, git extensions etc.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem as well. What worked for me, oddly enough, was not creating the repository via TortoiseGit, but rather via `git init`.